# Can diskpart take command line parameters? Or can I fake them with powershell?

Tags: powershell, diskpart

I understand I can [use `diskpart /s` to script diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart-scripts-and-examples)

```
select vdisk file=FILE_SUPPLIED_BY_COMMAND_LIME_PARAMETER
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
exit
```

And then run it with:

```
diskpart /s scriptname.txt /t 15
```

But **can I add command lime parameters to diskpart?** Eg so I can specify the VHDX file by the command line?

If that's not possible, faking command line parameters with a Powershell wrapper to make the diskpart script dynamically might also be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe to `diskpart`. I'd read the file and replace your values when the file contents are retrieved:

```
$diskPath = c:\disk.vhd
(Get-Content scriptname.txt) -replace 'FILE_SUPPLIED_BY_COMMAND_LIME_PARAMETER',$diskPath | diskpart
```

You can use a string and bypass reading a file:

```
$diskPath = 'c:\disk.vhd'
@"
select vdisk file=$diskPath
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
"@ | diskpart
```

If you want to use parameters, then you will need a function or script block. Using a script block:

```
# scriptname.txt contents
@"
select vdisk file=$($args[0])
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
"@ | diskpart

# The string argument for Invoke(argument) is passed to args[0]
[Scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content scriptname.txt -Raw)).Invoke('file path')
```

Using a function:

```
function Run-Diskpart {
    param($diskPath)

@"
select vdisk file=$diskPath
attach vdisk readonly
compact vdisk
detach vdisk
"@ | diskpart

}

Run-DiskPart 'c:\disk.vhd'
```